# omit intercept lines in plot of ordinal regression from "effects" package in r

Tags: r, plot, regression, effects, intercept

I want to visualize a mixed effects ordinal regression, fit using the clmm function within the `ordinal` package in r. I am using the `effects` package. However, I do not want the intercepts to be displayed on the plot (thresholds between response categories - seen as dashed horizontal lines below). Any guidance on how I can omit them?

Example code and plot:

```
library(ordinal)
library(MASS)
library(effects)

mod <- clmm(poverty ~ age + (1|country), data = WVS)
plot(Effect("age", mod, latent = TRUE))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It reads off the thresholds stored in your `eff` object.. Might have some other options in `plot.eff`, but for now you can write a function to set the threshold to `NULL` and plot:

```
plot_without_intercept = function(eff){
       eff$thresholds = NULL
       plot(eff)
}

Eff = Effect("age", mod, latent = TRUE)
plot_without_intercept(Eff)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works brilliantly. And just a heads up for other users in case this is helpful, other plot arguments (axis labels, colors, rug=FALSE, etc.) can continue to go in the plot() part of the function. That took me a second to figure out.